# Twitter api stream api rules: listen to a stream by a mention of two accounts where one is a constant and the other account can be any account

Tags: twitter, stream, twitter-streaming-api

How can I create twitter api stream rules to  listen to a stream by a mentions of two accounts, where one is a constant and the other account can be any account?

For example I would like to listen to a stream from `@example` account and `@<any other account>`, but the rule is the `@example` account must be mentioned plus any other account. I know how to listen to a mention of an account, but how do I enforce the rule as described above?